# What are the pros and cons of developing a web app using Parse vs. AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

From what I know, Parse offers convenient communication stacks for various platforms such as iOS, so it is easy to build clients that use your web app.

But Parse also seems to be tightly integrated with Facebook. If you were to build a web app that does not need Facebook, but that may integrate with Facebook in the long term, is Parse the clear winner over deploying directly to AWS, or are there important disadvantages to consider?

Comment: Parse integrates with many services like Twilio and Mailgun. Parse offers Facebook integration but it seems like you are thinking that it is somehow dependent on Facebook and it is not.  I've used parse with and without facebook, mostly without.  Facebook is just another option they offer.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand their page Parse is a PaaS (platform as a service) provider like Heroku and others while AWS is a IaaS (infrastructure as a service) provider.

**Pros for PaaS:**

- They care about the infrastructure
- You build your app on an existing platform
- For the start you don't need "ops-guys" as you don't do ops
- You can take their knowledge and prebuilt tools for your advance

**Pros for IaaS:**

- You have full control about the underlaying infrastructure
- You can start with a greenfield and build what ever you want
- You can use tools like Puppet / Chef / ... to control your servers
- You don't have to pay for the additional stuff you get when using PaaS
  (but have to pay your people for it)

So there is not a winner of this "battle" but you have to decide whether you want to use prebuilt tooling and give some independence for this or whether you want to have the absolute control over everything (nearly as you can't touch the hardware) and invest time and manpower into building your own tooling.

Comment: You forgot the financial angle: IaaS is usually cheaper than PaaS (compare AWS to Heroku) because you have to do a lot of stuff yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**"Better, Faster, Cheaper.."**

If you are pursuing mobile first strategy, Parse is a great tool for bootstrapping a mature, full web-presence from nothing more than an original beta app.

I dont have direct experience with AWS.

I have used Heroku/Parse integrating (very quickly) a stand alone mobile app with the back-end where the back end needs to cover following:

1. DB/persistence/noSql
2. Workflow - async tasks
3. REST API interface HTTP

Once the mobile app existed with only stubbed local data , Parse allowed a single engineer to build out ALL infrastructure mentioned above very quickly, taking the app from single user to multi-user with full DB and workflow that backs client side events with considerable server-side and cloud side business logic and process. Scaling related startup stuff that used to take weeks took only days.

The compression (time&money) when scaling up an app stack is really something. The Parse API did almost everything that i needed with one small exception (remuxing UGC media).

Personally, i abandoned the parse/android SDK in favor of a more robust REST API (threading on client-side and heavy HTTP activity ).

Developers used to Curl/REST dev stacks will take to Parse.